# What is the verb used when we pull the fishing rod when a fish takes bait, for example, "yank the fishing rod out of the water"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am teaching my child to fish

> -Put the bait on the hook
>
> -Let down the fishing rod into the water (I am not sure "**let down**" is a right word here)
>
> -When you feel a fish takes the bait, yank the fishing rod out of the water onto land (I decided to use "**yank**" because it is a hard
> quick sudden movement)

Do we say "**yank the fishing rod out of the water onto land**"?

Comment: You let the **line** down into the water, not the fishing rod.  The fishing rod is the stiff part that holds the line.

Comment: I would say "**lower** the line into the water" or even "lower the **hook** into the water"

Comment: You can also "**cast** the rod" or "**cast** the line", which involves a certain throwing motion to get the bait & the hook farther from the shore.  [See this video](https://youtu.be/7vEGGeDAUos?t=130) for what's meant by this.

Comment: I feel like pull would be the normal American expression.  Just Pull!

Comment: Since many sports/recreation activity terms diverge between AmE and BrE, probably you should mark your question with the `british-english` tag if you want answers that are specific for your country (I get from a comment that you're British).

Comment: You most definitely do not want to be yanking the rod, that is a sure-fire way to lose the fish. You cast your line, get a strike and snap your wrist upward  in one motion, which lifts the line and  sets the hook. I am working on an answer. Also, salt water fishing is usually with a spinning reel and angling (no spinning reel) is for freshwater.

Comment: A fishing line is **cast** into the water. If you are fishing without a rod, you can say let the line down into the water, but that is an exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 15):

When he gets a ***bite*** (he feels the line tightening, or sees the float bobbing), an angler ***strikes***...

> ***Striking** is the process of sweeping the fishing rod backwards when a bite is detected in order to securely set the hook in the mouth of a fish.*  [<sub>britishseafishing</sub>](https://britishseafishing.co.uk/techniques-and-info/playing-and-landing-fish/#:%7E:text=Striking%20is%20the%20process%20of,the%20mouth%20of%20a%20fish.)

In this context, ***to strike*** is almost always intransitive - you might occasionally encounter *The fisherman struck his **line***, but we almost never use *strike the **rod*** with this meaning.

---

EDIT
Votes and comments suggest that this sense of ***to strike*** may be primarily a *British* usage. I can't see any easy way to compare prevalence for this *exact* meaning, so I don't know how true that might be. But at least I can cite the relevant definition in the AmE-focused [Merriam-Webster dictionary...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strike)

> **strike**
> 11a: *to pull on a fishing rod in order to set the hook*
> 11b (of a fish): *to seize the bait*

(I don't recall the *second* of those senses being used in my childhood angling days in the UK.)

Comment: It's from britishseafishing and I've never heard it in the US, not sure what audience the OP is targeting.

Comment: In angling terminology, you **get a strike**, meaning the fish goes for the bait and you lift the rod upward in one motion (snap) to set the hook.

Comment: +1 But, Canada here, and "strike" to me has always meant a thing the *fish does* and not the person fishing (ie: def'n 11b above).  Definitely there's an [atlantic divide](https://www.boot.com/en/Magazine/Destinations/Differences_between_fishing_in_America_and_Britain) in the terminology.

Comment: Yeah, to me, a "strike" usually means a "hit" (except in baseball where it means a "miss" - language is weird)  This implies an outward force, where as pulling a fishing line is an inward force.  So it makes sense for the fish to do it, but less so for the angler, but nautical terminology is like a whole other language sometimes...

Comment: @J...: Yes, I see from your linked page that BrE ***bite*** is listed as equivalent to AmE ***strike***. Which accords with my own understanding, since I would never have said *I've got a strike!* with the meaning *A fish has grabbed my baited hook and is trying to swim off with it*. From my perspective, fish always bite and anglers always strike. I never did much "trolling" (the angling kind with spinners & spoons, not online stalking! :), but I doubt I'd have used "bite" in that context (a context where it might make sense to say the pike "struck", but I'd have just said ***I've got one**!*)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, trolling is usually done by trailing your fishing line in the water from a boat. And trolling can be done with lures that are flies (as in trout or bass fishing) or with hardware. Yes, fish bite and anglers strike. But for me, an angler is not some guy casting huge hardware lures off a boat in the sea... Angling is often associated with fly fishing, not lure fishing.

Comment: @Lambie: The full OED have a fairly extensive definition for the angling sense of ***troll***. Nothing seems to be certain about the etymology, but they draw attention to ***trawl*** several times as probably being influential. In the UK hardly anyone uses spinners / spoons anyway - to some extent, it's thought of a "unsporting", and it's mostly restricted to trolling for pike *in order to get rid of them* (so they don't eat all the *other* fish people are really trying to catch). But I gather trolling doesn't have such a bad press in the US.

Comment: (Unlike the US, there aren't many lakes in Britain where you'd be allowed to fish from a boat anyway.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can troll from a boat. In sea fishing, I am sure people use hardware and spinning reels for sea fishing. In freshwater, no, of course. And, I agree that hardware and spinning reels are not really used in freshwater in Britain. But only in Scotland will a gilly take you to the good spots. For freshwater anglers in the US, hardware/spinning reels etc. is also considered unsporting. And no one has even mentioned worms. That's how I started as a kid. Fishing for sunfish with worms on a little rod with a large hook.

Answer (score 12):

You can **jerk** the line. This is called

> **Setting the Hook**
> Pulling the rod in a jerking motion in order to lodge the hook in a fish’s mouth. Has to be done at just the right time.

Please see [Fishing Terms Every Angler Should Know](https://fishingbooker.com/blog/fishing-terms/)

The reason for yanking the line is to make the hook bite into the fish, which must then be landed with skill, rather then pulling the fish directly on to land with one big tug.

Comment: As a lad, I spent countless hours fishing. Many times someone else would have seen my float bobbing up and down, and shouted something like ***Strike! - you've got a bite!***. But I seriously doubt anyone ever shouted ***Jerk the line**!* in that situation.

Comment: I note that both this answer and the other answer currently responsive to the question both use the only term I have ever heard for the action: "setting the hook", while neither describes it.  And, to @Fumblefingers -- I was told many, many, many, many times to "Set the hook!".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your probably from England.

Comment: @EricTowers: I only included "set the hook" because it got scooped up by my cut&pasted definition of ***strike / striking***. Maybe professional adult anglers use that expression, but I'm sure no-one every used it near me when I went fishing as a child. It feels like an excessively "technical" expression for the OP here, in the context of teaching his child how to fish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wrote the answer this way, because of OP's description of what they do when they get a bite, which sounds as though they know less about fishing than I do.

Comment: @Lambie please tell that to the person who wrote the glossary I quoted - "in a jerking motion". I think this is getting out of hand: *my answer is better than yours* is very poor politics. Let's start downvoting other answers and race to the bottom.

Comment: @Lambie you are wrong. I have been fishing, been on fishing trips, but not very experienced. I have never been in a jerking war though.

Comment: @Lambie no, that's why I upvoted your answer. That was your answer, and this is mine. Geddit?? If you don't like it, downvote it. OP indicated they would say to yank the fish directly on to land. I said, no, you have to jerk / pull / twitch / whatever the line, to set the hook and *then* play in the fish.

Comment: @Lambie in that case this is posted on the wrong site. SE angling? *Is* angling the correct term? Please put me right. We *never* say "I am a fisher", but "I am an angler."

Comment: As children, we never went "angling". We only ever went *fishing*.

Comment: This looks very much like children still at play too, bickering over each others' answers.

Comment: You set the hook by making a sudden (but smooth) pulling motion on the rod which imparts a sharp jerk of the hook setting it in the fish's mouth. A sudden sharp movement. A jerk. So yeah, technically you might be "jerking the line" but we don't actually say that. Next we'll be seeing a debate over how many newton-meters of torque on the rod constitute jerking versus yanking versus pulling.

Comment: @Lambie "Jerk, pull, and twitch are all mistaken" - I don't know where you've been fishing, but where I grew up spending countless hours fishing, we would use jerk or pull to describe setting the hook quite often. Are you familiar with the term semantics?

Comment: @Lambie Do you hear the argument you're making? You're saying someone can't say jerk the line because they're actually jerking their wrist, which jerks the pole, which jerks the line... Once again, are you familiar with the term semantics? https://lmgtfy.app/?q=semantics+definition

Comment: @Lambie so OP should say to the child "When you feel a fish take the bait, snap the line"? Or would you say "give the line a gentle tug / jerk / pull..."?

Comment: Sure, that will just confuse the child.

Comment: @WeatherVane It isn't the line unless you are **line fishing**; It's the rod, in any case. Setting a hook is all in the wrist, if you are fishing with a rod. The kid would not be confused because you would show them.

Comment: In that case I recommend that you can teach all about casting too, a lesson which the expert surely could not resist... hang on.. I think you already gave an unasked lecture in casting, from the expert. Any more expert tips, please, from the expert? How about fly fishing? Trout?

Comment: In fly fishing, the wrist action is key. In fact, if you jerk it, you can lose the fish.

Comment: The kid will be out of its depth :)

Answer (score 8):

The act of bringing the fish to the shore or to a boat from the water is called [landing a fish](https://www.takemefishing.org/how-to-fish/how-to-catch-fish/how-to-land-a-fish/)**, whether with a reel, net, or by whatever other means.

A lot of fishing is done with a rod and reel. If you're fishing with a rod and reel, you might also say that you were [reeling in](https://www.takemefishing.org/how-to-fish/how-to-catch-fish/how-to-reel-in-fish/)** the fish.  This more specifically means using the reel to get the fish near to the shore or the boat using the reel.  You could reel in a fish but fail to land it, for example, if the fish got away at the last moment.

The other answers here are talking specifically about setting the hook, which is often done with a sharp jerk on the rod. At this point the fish is still in the water, however, and is not yet landed.  It sounds like you're talking about a single motion to haul a smaller type of fish directly onto shore, which is better described by the general term **landing**.

** No affiliation with the links - just a convenient example

Comment: but Americans don't say "**a reel**", they say "**a spool**" and we have the verb "**to reel in**". Do Americans say "**to spool the fish in**"?

Comment: @Tom No.  I'm not sure where you're getting any of that.

Comment: @Tom That is not true and that upvote is kind of annoying because it is wrong. Americans and British say reel and reel in a fish. Yes, landing a fish is also right. spooling is not right at all unless that is some unusual regionalism. One can't know them all.

Comment: Been fishing in America for 50+ years, and I've never called it a spool, nor has anyone else I know.  I've never brought my "rod and spool" with me, nor have I "spooled in" any fish. I buy a spool of line at the bait shop when I need to load my reel with new line. That's the only time a spool comes into it.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be a sharp jerk on the rod.  A normal person can do it, possibly better...

Comment: @J... - absolutely. Missed the point completely - didn't you.

Comment: @Tim Oh dear... get thee to a punnery, then.  Between the ambiguities of ESL here and the raging opinions on fishing technique, yes, I guess I missed the joke.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a dictionary for fishing, written in the UK with the differences in terminology for BrE/AmE. That said, the first thing is whether this is saltwater or fresh water fishing.

A rod with a fishing line is said to be cast into the water. (cast, cast, cast). "Oh, that was a great cast!" "Where did you learn to cast like that?"

In freshwater fly fishing, the nice broad motion of getting the line into the water is considered an art and it is called: casting. That is because a spinning reel is not used. If using a spinning reel in fresh or salt water, casting is very easy. Without a spinning reel, it is not easy and you have to learn how to handle the line and reel.

However, **in both cases**, a fish is said to strike (go for the bait), whether in fishing in saltwater or freshwater on both sides of the pond.
At this level, there really is no difference in terminology.

[fishing terminology with BrE and AmE terms](https://www.fish-uk.com/dictionary.htm#BookmarkS)

Strike:
**this is when a fisherwoman or fisherman gets a bite from a fish and lifts his or her wrist upwards with a snap in an arc in an attempt to set the hook into a fish**

Setting a hook:
striking at a bite to set the hook into the fish's mouth.

To set a hook you snap your wrist upward which will lift the line. The line (the rod) is then lifted as a result of the wrist motion.

Please note: When you get a strike, **you never, ever yank or jerk the line**. That is a sure-fire way to lose a fish. **The hook will not set**. You raise the rod from your wrist in one single motion. You snap your wrist to set the hook. (Please note: the word snap is tricky as when a line breaks it is said to snap).

Basically, when you get a strike in freshwater fishing, or angling (fly fishing), you raise the rod from a 45 degree or slightly higher angle in one motion of the wrist. This is called **setting the hook**. In ocean fishing off a boat, when a fish strikes, they usually start to run so the hook sets itself. This can also happen in fresh water when you are fishing off a boat.

[setting a hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_set#:%7E:text=In%20recreational%20fishing%20terminology%2C%20the,a%20fishing%20lure%20or%20bait.)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if the rod is in the water, you're not in with a good start to 'learn to fish'!

When a fish 'takes the bait' it's nibbling at it. That causes the float (when attached to the line) to bob in the water. At that stage, you have not hooked the fish. For that to happen, the rod (in the air!) needs to be sharply swung away from the fish's direction. That gives the hook impetus to penetrate inside the mouth of said fish.

That's the **strike**. More often than not, the fish will remain in the water - unless it's a tiddler - and will need playing as the line is reeled in, until the fish tires and is close enough to be *landed*, hopefully in a net.

With no real clues, it's difficult to determine whether the terminology should be explained in U.S. or British English. Maybe 'Yank' is a clue..?

Comment: Ha ha, that's right. If the rod is in the water, you ain't fishing. You fish with a float attached to the line when fishing with hardware-type lures.